# Why doesn't this program end?

Tags: java, sockets

I was expecting to receive the HTTP response and then for the `Socket` to be closed but it just sits there never ending after the page is returned. I'm assuming it is to do with the `Scanner`; why doesn't this program ever end?

```
public class PingHost {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Socket s = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
      out.writeBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
      while (sc.hasNext())
         System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
      System.out.println("never gets to here");
      s.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: because of `while (sc.hasNext())`

Comment: But there is no more input coming from google, so why doesn't the Scanner empty every? Nothing is being printed either.

Comment: The other end has to explicitly close the socket. I don't know why Google takes so much to do so, but it closes here after ~2min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29)

> This method may block while waiting for input to scan

Answer (score 2):

It's a stream, so Java can't predict when and where input is over. You need to specify some "ending token", find it and stop reading.

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      String str = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println(str);
      if(str.endsWith("</HTML>")) break;
}
```